# reload component/page without refreshing the entire page in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

After a user has selected a file to upload, the file is only visible after a reload the entire page. I am looking for a neater way for the reload to happen so that I can display the document.

```
 public onFileSelected(event): void {

  console.log(this.fileId)
   const file = event.target.files[0];
   if (file) {
     const formData = new FormData();

     formData.append("file", file, file.name);
     this.testService.postUrl(`${this.fileId}/upload-document`, formData)
     .subscribe((data) => {
       Swal.fire("Document", "The document has been uploaded.", "success");
     });
   }
   this.getDocuments();
   //this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
   const RedirectUrl ='/portal/docupload/' + this.fileId
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/portal/docupload/' + this.fileId, {skipLocationChange: true}).then(() => {
   this.router.navigate([RedirectUrl]);
   this.active = 4;
   // When skipLocationChange true, navigates without pushing a new state into history.
   });
 }
```

Comment: you should not reload the page or the component but simply display the image.
You need to show the code where you display the image in order to get help.

probably you should move ` this.getDocuments();` and the navigation in the `subscibe()` i guess you want to do that after to upload has compelted

Comment: Just update the model after uploading.  The upload endpoint can just return the model, or just the uploaded item's id. (or path, better to use id in src so you can authenticate the request)  Once the model is updated the page will reflect that... ex (for multiple images):  <div *ngIf="yourModel?.images!.length>0">
 <span *ngFor="let thisImage of yourModel?.images; let i=index"> ... insert image...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reload the component because component only iniatlize only one time. you can make a method and and then call the method and change state of the component variables.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reload the whole component.
Steps to resolve the issue:

1. create variable like fileURL and assign the path or URL of file.
2. You can show it on UI side with {{fileURL}}.

Please let me known if you don't understand, I will create a working example for you.